# Add value to an identical row from a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets. 
First worksheet has the columns: ID - UNIT - ENGLISH - DUTCH- WOORDSOORT - VOORBEELDZIN - FOTO

The second worksheet has the columns: UNIT - ENGLISH - DUTCH- WOORDSOORT - VOORBEELDZIN - FOTO - THEMA - SUBTHEMA

I want to add the values of "THEMA" AND "SUBTHEMA" from a row in the second worksheet to an identical row in the first worksheet. If "UNIT - ENGLISH - DUTCH - WOORDSOORT - VOORBEELDZIN - FOTO" from a row in the first worksheet is identical to a row in the second worksheet, add the value "THEMA" AND "SUBTHEMA" from that row to that row in the first worksheet.

The 2 worksheets are slightly different, so I can't just copy paste the additional column.

Comment: With your two worksheets, are there the same rows but in a different order?  Or is there only a subset of same rows between the two worksheets?  Are these worksheets in the same workbook?

Comment: Can you please provide any code that you tried to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. It`s a fast draft, it can be done more elegantly using arrays. But, you get the idea.

```
Sub AddValue()

Dim bytHeadersRowDestination As Byte, bytHeadersRow As Byte
Dim bytFirstColumnSource As Byte, bytFirstColumnDestination As Byte
Dim shtSource As Worksheet, shtDestination As Worksheet
Dim intLastRow As Integer 'change to long if you have more than 32 767 rows in database

'change Byte data type to something bigger (integer, long) if you have the tables in column 255 or further to the right
Dim bytSourceUnitColumn As Byte, bytSourceEnglishColumn As Byte
Dim bytSourceDutchColumn As Byte, bytSourceWoordsoortColumn As Byte
Dim bytSourceVoorbeeldzinColumn As Byte, bytSourceFotoColumn As Byte
Dim bytSourceThemaColumn As Byte, bytSourceSubThemaColumn As Byte

Dim bytDestinationUnitColumn As Byte, bytDestinationEnglishColumn As Byte
Dim bytDestinationDutchColumn As Byte, bytDestinationWoordsoortColumn As Byte
Dim bytDestinationVoorbeeldzinColumn As Byte, bytDestinationFotoColumn As Byte
Dim bytDestinationThemaColumn As Byte, bytDestinationSubThemaColumn As Byte

Dim intComparedRow As Integer

'change the values to your situation, presuming you have the tables on the same range, only in different sheets
bytHeadersRow = 1
bytFirstColumn = 1
Set shtSource = Worksheets(2)
Set shtDestination = Worksheets(1)

intLastRow = shtSource.Cells(bytHeadersRow, bytFirstColumn).End(xlDown).Row 'presuming you dont have blank cells in database

'find the column headers, you can replace this with simply setting the column numbers by hand. If they will always be on the same spot, that should work fine.
With shtSource.Cells()

    bytSourceUnitColumn = .Find(what:="UNIT").Column
    bytSourceEnglishColumn = .Find(what:="ENGLISH").Column
    bytSourceDutchColumn = .Find(what:="DUTCH").Column
    bytSourceWoordsoortColumn = .Find(what:="WOORDSOORT").Column
    bytSourceVoorbeeldzinColumn = .Find(what:="VOORBEELDZIN").Column
    bytSourceFotoColumn = .Find(what:="FOTO").Column
    bytSourceThemaColumn = .Find(what:="Thema").Column
    bytSourceSubThemaColumn = .Find(what:="SubThema").Column

End With

With shtDestination.Cells()

    bytDestinationUnitColumn = .Find(what:="UNIT").Column
    bytDestinationEnglishColumn = .Find(what:="ENGLISH").Column
    bytDestinationDutchColumn = .Find(what:="DUTCH").Column
    bytDestinationWoordsoortColumn = .Find(what:="WOORDSOORT").Column
    bytDestinationVoorbeeldzinColumn = .Find(what:="VOORBEELDZIN").Column
    bytDestinationFotoColumn = .Find(what:="FOTO").Column
    bytDestinationThemaColumn = .Find(what:="Thema").Column
    bytDestinationSubThemaColumn = .Find(what:="SubThema").Column

End With

'compare the 2 data rows, presuming they are on the same row, same number of data rows
For intComparedRow = bytHeadersRow + 1 To intLastRow

    If shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceUnitColumn) = shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationUnitColumn) And _
    shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceEnglishColumn) = shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationEnglishColumn) And _
    shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceDutchColumn) = shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationDutchColumn) And _
    shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceWoordsoortColumn) = shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationWoordsoortColumn) And _
    shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceVoorbeeldzinColumn) = shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationVoorbeeldzinColumn) And _
    shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceFotoColumn) = shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationFotoColumn) Then

    shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationThemaColumn) = shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceThemaColumn)
    shtDestination.Cells(intComparedRow, bytDestinationSubThemaColumn) = shtSource.Cells(intComparedRow, bytSourceSubThemaColumn)

    End If

Next intComparedRow

End Sub
```